# check-box check before delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a check-box for each user and the value of the **check-box** is the **user id**

What is the best suitable JavaScript Which disables the delete a.button until have clicked the correct corresponding **check-box**

If button is disabled I would like to be able to use bootstraps disabled="disabled"

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="user">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_username;?></a></b></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_status;?></a></b></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_date_added;?></a></b></td>
        <td class="text-right"><b><?php echo $column_action;?></b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($users) { ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" />
</td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['status']; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['date_added']; ?></td>
<td class="text-right">
<a href="<?php echo $user['edit']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit User</a>
<a href="<?php echo $user['delete']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Delete User</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, all the delete buttons should be disabled when you first load the HTML. You can add the `disabled='disabled'` attribute to each delete button in your PHP code.

Then in JavaScript you look for a change event on the checkbox:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var thisRow = $(this).parents("tr");
  if(this.checked) {
    thisRow.find("a.btn-danger").attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    thisRow.find("a.btn-danger").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```